# Get the user data from firebase cloud-based database and convert into dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, xcode8

I am new to swift and I am trying to get the data from the firebase cloudbase database and trying to assign them in dictionary.

I have tried putting them on a dictionary and printing the values but it doesnot show anyerror message or print anything on the console.

```
func fetchUser(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
               for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                if let dict = document as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    let email = dict["email"] as! String
                    print(email)
                }
               }
             }
         }
    }
```

I want to print all the email from the users collection and display on the console.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```swift
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
    let documentValue = document.data() // default dictionary
    print(documentValue["email"] as! String)
}
```