# Get data from firestore and assign it to an array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore collection and assign it to an array of dictionaries. for this part of the code below... i get the error "Cast from 'QuerySnapshot?' to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]' always fails" and the console prints "is not working".

```
guard let snap = snapshot as? [[String:Any]] else {
                print("is not working")
                completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                return
            }
```

Here is the full code.

```
 // fetches and returns all conversations for the user with passed in uid
public func getAllConversations(for uid: String, completion: @escaping(Result<[Conversation], Error>) -> Void) {
    
    print("fetching all convos")
    
    //NEW
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let CurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ListRef = db.collection("users").document(CurrentUser!).collection("conversations")
    
    // fetch the current users convo list
    ListRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot as? [[String:Any]] else {
                print("is not working")
                completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                return
            }
            print("is working")
            let conversations: [Conversation] = snap.compactMap({ dictionary in
                guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? String,
                      let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                      let otherUserUID = dictionary["other_user-uid"] as? String,
                      let latestMessage = dictionary["latest-message"] as? [String:Any],
                      let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                      let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                      let isRead = latestMessage["is-read"] as? Bool else {
                    return nil
                }
                
                //save other user ID to a global var
                self.test = otherUserUID
                
                //assign data into an array of dictionaries
                let latestConvoObject = LatestMessage(date: date, text: message, isRead: isRead)
                
                return Conversation(id: id, name: name, otherUserUid: otherUserUID, latestMessage: latestConvoObject)
                
            })
            completion(.success(conversations))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the user data from firebase cloud-based database and convert into dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586034/get-the-user-data-from-firebase-cloud-based-database-and-convert-into-dictionary)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, no this is now to fetch the data from firestore but then how do i assign the fetch data to an array of dictionaries?

Comment: for doc in (snapshot?.documents)! {}

Comment: I am able to fetch the data from firestore as a dictionary but now i want to assign that dictionary to an array, is this possible?

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do this but two important questions. 1) Why an array of dictionaries?  2) The code in the question appears to be an array of Conversations, not dictionaries. Can you clarify? Oh - as a side note, in programming, Upper case objects are generally reserved for Structs and Classes so don't do this `let ListRef = db.collection` - it should be `listRef`.

Comment: Yes as you say it will be an array of conversations i.e something that looks like this [(name:John, age:24, gender:male),(name:Luke, age:32, gender:male),(name:Sarah, age:48, gender:female)]. It is essentially storing information for all the users in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a numbers of way to read that data, and the process can be simplified by [conforming objects to the codable protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) but let me provide a straight forward example. I don't know what your Conversation object looks like so here's mine

```
class ConversationClass {
    var from = ""
    var to = ""
    var msg = ""
    var timestamp = 0

    convenience init(withDoc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.from = withDoc.get("from") as? String ?? "no from"
        self.to = withDoc.get("to") as? String ?? "no to"
        self.msg = withDoc.get("msg") as? String ?? "no msg"
        self.timestamp = withDoc.get("timestamp") as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

and then here's the the code that reads in all the conversation documents  from a Collection, stores each in a ConversationClass object, puts those in an array and returns it through an escaping completion handler

```
func getConversations(completion: @escaping( [ConversationClass] ) -> Void) {
    let conversationCollection = self.db.collection("conversations")
    conversationCollection.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        var convoArray = [ConversationClass]()

        for doc in docs {
            let convo = ConversationClass(withDoc: doc)
            convoArray.append(convo)
        }

        completion(convoArray)
    })
}
```